# Sending mail from Chrome extension using auth 2.0 but stuck at somewhere I don't know

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, gmail-api

I want to send email from Chrome extension where user has to enter the email address of the reciepent in the extenion popup window, and the link of the current opened tab will be sent to the entered email address, but I am stuck in the authentication part, it asks for the password of my email as shown in the.

After I enter, it reloads the same page instead of sending the mail. Please help me out where I am getting wrong.
The code is for popup.js page.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', getCurrentTabAndUrl);

});

function getCurrentTabAndUrl() {

  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {

        var tabId = tab.id;
        var tabTitle=tab.title;
        var tabUrl = tab.url;
        if (tabUrl=="chrome://newtab/") {
          document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="Looks like you opened a new tab, please open a web page and click again to Share.";
        }else {
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML="subject="+tabTitle+'<br/>'+tabUrl;

        var to=document.getElementById("to").value;


        sendMessage('me',to,tabTitle,tabUrl);

        }
    });
}


function sendMessage(userId,to,subject,email) {

  authUser();

  var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(email);

  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({

    'userId': userId,

    'message': {
      'raw': base64EncodedEmail,

      "headers":[
        {"To":to},
        {"Subject":subject}
          ]
    }
  });

  request.execute();

}

function authUser(){

    chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
    {'interactive': true},
    function(token){
     // load Google's javascript client libraries
     var url="https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?access_token="+token;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState !== 4||request.status !== 200) {
            return;
        }

   var response=JSON.parse(request.responseText);
   console.log(response);

    };
    request.open('POST', url,true);

    request.send();
    request.setRequestHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + token);
    });

}
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug it?  Are there errors in the javascript console, either in the background or the browser console?

Comment: Can we see your manifest file? Also have you registered the valid client id in manifest json ?

Comment: Please keep the language tag intact; SO relies on it for syntax highlight. By the way, it would help if you edited your code to be more compact and consistent (less empty lines, 2-space indentation)

Answer (score 1):

After invoking `authUser()`, which calls an asynchronous API `chrome.identity.getAuthToken`, you're *immediately* sending the email so it fails as the token hasn't yet been acquired.

Move that part into a callback which will be executed after `getAuthToken` completes:

```
function sendMessage(userId, to, subject, email) {
    authUser(function() {
        var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(email);
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
            'userId': userId,
            'message': {
                'raw': base64EncodedEmail,
                'headers': [
                    {'To': to}, 
                    {'Subject': subject}
                ]
            }
        });
        request.execute();
    });
}

function authUser(callback) {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true}, function(token) {
        // load Google's javascript client libraries
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?access_token=" + token;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState !== 4 || request.status !== 200) {
                return;
            }
            var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            console.log(response);
            callback();
        }
        ;
        request.open('POST', url, true);
        request.send();
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    });
}
```