# Use Gmail API to send mail in a Chrome App

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a Chrome app and I want to send **email**. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741960/sending-mail-from-chrome-extension-using-auth-2-0-but-stuck-at-somewhere-i-dont), but I can't figure out how make it work.

```
function sendMessage(userId, to, subject, email) {
    authUser(function() {
        var base64EncodedEmail = btoa(email);
        var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send({
            'userId': userId,
            'message': {
                'raw': base64EncodedEmail,
                'headers': [
                    {'To': to}, 
                    {'Subject': subject}
                ]
            }
        });
        request.execute();
    });
}

function authUser(callback) {
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true}, function(token) {
        // load Google's javascript client libraries
        var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send?access_token=" + token;
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState !== 4 || request.status !== 200) {
                return;
            }
            var response = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            console.log(response);
            callback();
        }
        ;
        request.open('POST', url, true);
        request.send();
        request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    });
}
```

I put the code in my *background.js* (call sendMessage on launch), and get the following *manifest.json* :

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "Description",
  "permissions": [
        "storage",
        { "fileSystem": ["write"] },
        "identity",
        "https://mail.google.com/"],

  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "oauth2": {
        "client_id": "XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",
        "scopes": [
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"
    ]   
    },
    "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": [
            "background.js"]
    }
  },
  "icons": { "16": "images/mailling-16.png", "128": "images/mailling-128.png" }
}
```

So, I understand that we need to establish the connection (with our credentials) with **Gmail API** and then we **send the mail**.
But I am having **HTTP error 400** on the *POST* request and server throw : *'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required*

I don't see why he is expecting a message, whereas we are establishing the connection :I

Answer (score 0):

My best solution is to switch to [google script apps](https://script.google.com), you can send mail in only one with **MailApp.sendEmail**.

Anyway, that's not a solution for Chrome app.